# Adding Bootstrap 4 to project causing dimensions measured in em to collapse

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a strange issue: when I add Bootstrap 4 to my project, this element's width and height suddenly collapse to 0:

[image]

becomes

[image]

The width and height of this element are measured in `em`. Changing them to `px` fixes the issue; is Bootstrap affecting the scale of `em` somehow?

If it matters, this element is positioned absolutely with its immediate parent being positioned relatively. It also has a `transform: translate(...)` applied to it.

What might be causing this?

Strangely, taking a look at the Computed tab of Chrome's developer tools, I found this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: when bootstrap 5 comes ?

Comment: @NishargShah Oops wrong number

Comment: can you share your code ?